# Django filter not using correct template

Tags: python, django, templates, filter

I am working on a Django web application.   The app includes a filter that is calling the wrong template--even though 'template_name' is set in both the view and the filter.  I don't understand why the template_name attribute is being ignored.

Here's the code:

```
in urls.py:

    path('curation/',
     views.SubjectsCurationView.as_view(),
     name='subjects_curation'),
```

in views.py:

```
class SubjectsCurationView(LoginRequiredMixin, FilterView):
    template_name = 'subjects_curation.html'
    filterset_class = filters.CurationFilter

    in filters.py:

class CurationFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    template_name = 'subjects_curation.html'
    projects = django_filters.ModelMultipleChoiceFilter(
        queryset=Project.objects.all(),
        field_name='projects',
        widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple()
    )

    class Meta:
        model = models.Subject
        fields = [
            'projects',
         ]
        
    @property
    def qs(self):
        queryset = super().qs
        return queryset
```

The template that does get called, subjects_filter.html, is different from the subjects_curation.html template that is specified here.

I tried changing the order of the url entries in case lazy matching was part of the problem, but that made no difference.

Joe White
Dana-Farber CI

Answer (score 0):

The canonical way is always to have app-specific templates prefixed with the app name:

```
template_name = 'app/subjects_curation.html'
```

and an extra, empty, level in the folder heirarchy

```
project/app/templates/app/subjects_curation.html
```

I've never completely understood why. But if you do it this way, it all "just works".

Comment: Thank you.  This is helpful.  The first item you mentioned was the problem.